# Linux detects sata ssd only with ACPI=off, but windows always does

Tags: linux, gentoo, ssd, acpi

I'm trying to install Linux on my new Intel 525 SSD (240gb), however none of the linux installers detect it. I've tried Debian Testing, Gentoo, Gparted live, and Arch Linux live usbs - none of them detect my ssd, only my hdd. What's interesting is that both windows 7 installation usb and already installed windows successfully see my ssd. Furthermore, in Arch Linux live usb, there is an option during boot called "Hardware Information (HDT)" and I can see my ssd there, but after actually booting the iso `lsblk` onlly shows my hdd and usb stick itself, but not the ssd.

What I've done:

- Updated bios.
- Updated ssd firmware.

What I've tried:

- Playing with UEFI options (Legasy support, only bios, only uefi...
  etc)
- Disabling/Enabling certain bios options (Virtualization, IDE/SATA
  modes, etc)
- Falling back to bios defaults
- Trying different usb sticks
- Playing with `doscsi` `nodmraid` `scandelay` `nosata` boot options in
  Gentoo live usb
- Removing my hdd thus leaving ssd alone

Yeah, and the laptop I'm doing it on is a Lenovo m50-70.

EDIT: I have just discovered that using Gentoo live usb and acpi=off setting I am able to see, mount and use my ssd (finally), but! Acpi=off disables any hyperthreading support, which is not really cool.

EDIT2: pci=noacpi allows hyperthreading, ssd is detectable. Best option so far.

Comment: Can you post your full `dmesg` output for boots with `acpi=on`, `acpi=off`,   `pci=noacpi`. This sounds like the device needs a quirk added to the kernel so that it turns up properly.